# Recent news about Tokamak

Tags: experimental-physics, fusion

I first heard about the Tokamak in highschool 10 years ago and was wondering how far the technology has come since then.  Can it sustain a reaction for more than a few seconds?  Are these devices still huge or have they been made on a smaller scale?

Comment: I suppose you've already checked the [wikipedia list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokamak#Currently_in_operation)?

Comment: @Marek: Yes, I was looking for more of an intuitive idea of how successful these devices are.

Comment: more seriously, ITER should be operative by 2018, but there is skepticism that you can reach breakeven, that is, that it will be able to produce more energy than it consumes, with tokamak technology

Comment: Update: "*ITER should be operative by 2018*": 2025 [is the current (2018) estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITER#Timeline_and_current_status).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can it sustain a reaction for more than a few seconds?

Yes, at [JET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_European_Torus).
*Lifetime of the plasma: 20–60 s*

At [ITER](http://www.iter.org/mach/cryo):
*It will operate over a wide range of ITER plasma scenarios, from short plasma pulses (a few hundred seconds) with enlarged fusion power (700 MW) to long plasma pulses of 3,000 s*

> Are these devices still huge or have they been made on a smaller scale?

They have to be large in order to give out more energy than they consume. This is the [ITER](http://www.iter.org/) link, the one planned and already being built, to get the size idea.

Comment: [Tore Supra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tore_Supra) tokamak was working with discharges up to 400 seconds for a long time now. Here is a [paper](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1238/Physica.Topical.111a00023/meta) from 2004, for instance, with discharges around 250 s.